# How to change the color on top an image using hover in tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I do not understand how to place a color transition effect over an image such as changing the color that will lay on top of the image when i hover over it. Basically i want a hover effect on my image, lets say to the color blue. I tried searching google for this but i cant find any answers to my question. Im new to tailwind but i did try hover:bg-blue-400 but it did not work, im currently using version 3 of tailwind. Here is an example

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center rounded-2xl p-6">
      <img src="./images/myImage.jpg" alt="image" class="hover:bg-blue-400">
</div>
```

Comment: I finally got it, sorry for asking this question

Answer (score 2):

The answer is make a div with the color of your choice then within that place
the img tag within it lets say hover:opacity-25 then your good. like so...

```
<div class="bg-blue-400 rounded-xl">
  <img src="./image.jpg" alt="image" class="hover:opacity-25 rounded-xl">
</div>
```